# AngularJS Graphs & Charts - Mix of solid & dotted

Tags: css, angularjs, user-interface, zingchart

I've been working with `ZingChart` & `AngularJS` to print some graphs & charts.

I've searching for graph that it solid in the end is dotted, something like:

[image: grpah]

There is a way to do so? maybe with other framework\library other then `ZingChart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. A mix of solid and dotted lines is quite easy to implement with [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/) using [rules](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/elements/rules). Inside a series entry, add a rules property that will change the line style from solid to dashed after a  node index value as shown below.

```
"rules": [
    {
      "rule": "%i > 4",
      "line-style": "dashed",
    }
  ]
```

I've attached a screenshot of the result and a [demo](https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/create/4DFNP6WH) for your reference.

I hope this helps. Please feel free to reach out in case you have more questions.

[image]